# Как выглядит структура папок многостраничного сайта?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, dom

Как у меня в голове это всё:

- в корне создать папку pages и в ней создавать папки с названием страницы и уже в этих папках index.html (pages/about/index.html)
- Если страницы разные, то создаю новые файлы в папке css (которая в корне) отдельные файлы .css (about.css, portfolio).

Я просто видел уже чужие проекты (где не одна страница) и там по разному у всех. У одного в папке pages .html файлы, а в папке css файлы .css к этим новым страницам. У второго все .html файлы лежат тупо в корне без каких либо папок.

**Вопрос**:

- или это просто дело вкуса. То есть кому как удобно.
- как быть с файлами ксс если главная страница наполовину или даже меньше половины похожа на все остальные? То есть даже если хоть немного страницы различаются, то создавать отдельные ксс?

Comment: Это дело вкуса, то есть кому как удобно - поэтому у всех по-разному.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильнее делать один общий css и к каждой странице добавочные css.
Это верно, если страницы различаются хотя бы на треть.
Если же брать сайт из реальной жизни, а не из каких-то примеров, то так не бывает, страницы отличаются сугубо контентом, но не стилями  и единственно правильное решение - только один css на все страницы.
Что-то подобное - разные стили для разных компонентов, включаемых на разных страницах - используется в битриксе, но там сложный механизм кеширования, создающие разные варианты кеша для разных страниц, у вас статика и кеширование отсутствует как класс...
И не идите на поводу у слова ВКУС. Вкусы - понятие субъективное, а вот требования гугла и яндекса к качеству сайтов - формализованы и тщательно прописаны, разные css будут отражаться на скорости загрузки страницы и т.д.